# Hovering over an image changes different div

Tags: html, css

so I have 3 images next to each other and a text box below. I have default text and when I hover over one of the images, I want it to change that text to something else, and then when I hover over the 2nd image it does the same but with different text etc. I'm unsure on how to do this, so any help will be very appreciated!

Here's my HTML:

```html
<div class="mak-item">
  <div class="mak-item-container">
    <img data-tilt data-tilt-scale="1.1" class="makitem1" src="images/mak-item-1.png">
    <img data-tilt data-tilt-scale="1.1" class="makitem2" src="images/mak-item-2.png">
    <img data-tilt data-tilt-scale="1.1" class="makitem3" src="images/mak-item-3.png">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mak-item-text">
  <div class="mak-item-text-wrapper fade-in">
    <div id="default-text">
      <p class="mak-item-name">Item Name</p>
      <br>
      <p class="mak-subtypes">Subtypes</p>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p class="mak-cooldown">Cooldown</p>
      <p class="mak-cost">Cost</p>
      <p class="mak-size">Size</p>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p class="mak-effect-heading">Effect</p>
      <p class="mak-effect">Effect Here</p>
      <br>
      <p class="mak-passive-heading">Passive</p>
      <p class="mak-passive">Passive Here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Benjamin, welcome to SO! You need to place the text (I assume `.mak-item-text`) you want to show next to the `<img>` in your HTML with CSS `.mak-item-text { display: hidden }`. When hovering over the image you need CSS `img:hover + .mak-item-text { display: block }`. Regarding getting better help read how to create a [reprex]. There are all kinds of solutions, this is just one...

Comment: Thanks for the help! That's essentially it, and I did try that, but for some reason, my text isn't disappearing. I also want it so that when I hover over the second image, I want it to display different text to the first one.

Answer (score 0):

With this solution, on image hover the desired text will be displayed.

Try this:

```js
const img = document.querySelectorAll('img');

const text = document.querySelectorAll('.text')


img.forEach((element) => {
    element.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    switch (element.id) {
    case "img1":
        text[0].style.display = "block";
    break;
    case "img2":
        text[1].style.display = "block";
    break;
    case "img3":
        text[2].style.display = "block";
    break;
  }
  })
  
    element.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    switch (element.id) {
    case "img1":
        text[0].style.display = "none";
    break;
    case "img2":
        text[1].style.display = "none";
    break;
    case "img3":
        text[2].style.display = "none";
    break;
  }
  })
});
```

```css
.text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="na" id="img1">
  <img src="na" id="img2">
  <img src="na" id="img3">
</div>

<div class="text">
<p>
This is the first image text
</p>
</div>

<div class="text">
<p>
This is the second image text
</p>
</div>

<div class="text">
<p>
This is the three image text
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: My text didn't disappear and therefore it doesn't work for me. I searched up why and found a solution to put !important after "display: none", and tried again but still doesn't work, unsure why though.

Comment: Hi Benjamin! This example works perfectly. I create a project for you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-avssuh?file=index.html

Comment: Thank you, I tried to use it in my code but hasn't worked, then tried it on a test website with nothing on and didn't work again. I'll figure it out (hopefully)! Thanks again :)

Comment: Perhaps in your code you are not calling the script. Try calling it in the <head> tag with the defer attribute. Something like this: <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js" defer></script> I will be happy to help you if you can update the post if you need to provide more information.